# Facebook token permanent

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Nowadays with the new Api, the token that you can generate to do consult about event for example expired when pass only one hour,  i need to generate a Token that dosent expired or at least i could use two months...

I would like to know is there are any options to do this, my app only consults events with the next sentence:

```
var uri="https://graph.facebook.com/search?access_token=#KEY#&q=#QUERY#&type=event";
```

But i dont want that my app conect each hour to facebook.

Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extend your short-lived (2 hours) User Access Token into a long-lived (60 days) one as outlined at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens#extending

Sample call:

```
GET /oauth/access_token?  
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&           
    client_id={app-id}&
    client_secret={app-secret}&
    fb_exchange_token={short-lived-token}
```

Comment: It dosent work for me because i dont want to register an app, i want to do a search using a token is different.

Comment: You need an app to be able to get a long-lived Access Token. Read the docs. Registering an app takes 2 minutes, so I don't get why you don't want to do this. And why the downvote?

Comment: For that i asked for a solution, i have read 20 times the docs. I dont want to register an app because really i dont use a app base in facebook i only want to search things in someplaces.

Comment: I gave you a solution. There is no other way. Maybe you should read more thorougly then. Or hire somebody.